# Difference between two datepicker in Backbonejs

Tags: backbone.js, backbone-views, backbone-events

Can anyone tell me how to make difference between two datepickers in backbonejs ? 
I try to make it like that in my view  but it alerts a NAN :

```
initialize: function () {

 this.model.on("change:auprov",function(){
                       var datedeb = new Date(this.model.get("auprov"));
                       var dateret = new Date(this.model.get("deprov"));
                       var diff_ms = dateret.getTime() - datedeb.getTime();
                       alert(diff_ms/1000/60/60/24);
                       //this.model.set({"dureeprov": '5'});
                                        },this);
    },
```

Here is a part of my model :

```
deprov:{
type: "DatePicker",
title: "De (Prov.)",
fieldAttrs:{
        className:'col-sm-2 deprov'
    },
validators: ["required"]
  },
auprov:{
type: "DatePicker",
title: "Au (Prov.)",
fieldAttrs:{
        className:'col-sm-2 auprov'
    },
validators: ["required"]
  },
```

Regards

Comment: What are `this.model.get("auprov")` and `this.model.get("deprov")`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry I was using French datepicker form, so i had to change it to english one, here the correct code :

```
this.model.on("change:auprov",function(){
        var myDateArrayRet = this.model.get("auprov").split("/");
        var dateret = new Date(myDateArrayRet[2],myDateArrayRet[1]-1,myDateArrayRet[0]);
        var myDateArray = this.model.get("deprov").split("/");
        var datedeb = new Date(myDateArray[2],myDateArray[1]-1,myDateArray[0]);
        var diff_ms = dateret.getTime() - datedeb.getTime();
        alert(Math.ceil(diff_ms / (1000 * 3600 * 24)));
        },this);
```

Comment: Is this a solution for your problem or update to question?

Comment: This is a solution, let me explain, My datepicker takes french format (Days/Months/years intead of Months/days/years) so I had to swap data and then use new Date(..).

Regards

Answer (score 0):

Until i cannot know for sure the content and types of `this.model.get("auprov")` and `this.model.get("deprov")` i can only make an assumption that these are numbers. Javascript sometimes handle numbers as strings. So to correct it use `parseInt` to convert string to number.

```
var datedeb = new Date(parseInt(this.model.get("auprov")));
var dateret = new Date(parseInt(this.model.get("deprov")));
```

Comment: Thank you @Simo for ur answer, i was mistaken i used french datepicker format so when i try 26 june 2016 it considers 26 as month and it gives invalid date, i will add correction of my issue.